# View Source and Chrome Developer Tools showing different output

Tags: html, css, xhtml

When viewing a page in Chrome and Firefox, they show a really small h1 title, and also it changes color as if it is a link. 
The template that generates everything looks exactly how it should be. 
When diagnosing the issue, the relevant section of code looks like this when I go to view source:

```
<div class="page-heading">
    <h1>Title Here</h1>
</div>
```

However, when I go to view it in Chrome's Developer tools, it is throwing in extraneous malformed anchor tags, which is obviously causing the hovering behavior. This is what it looks like to the dev tools:

```
<div class="page-heading">
<h1>
    <a style="font-family: arial; font-size: 9px" <="" a="">Title Here</a>
</h1>                
</div>
```

In addition, when viewing a local copy of the site, the output shown in the dev tools is the same as viewing the source and they both render correctly locally.

Oddly enough, all version of IE render it correctly. The current version of both Chrome and Firefox both render it weirdly. Initially I thought it may be a user agent stylesheet problem, but if anything the CSS is fine, it's the HTML that is malformed.

Comment: I think is caused by some script. I can see the same with Firebug.

Comment: That's a lot of inline styles.

Comment: Understatement of the year @cimmanon. Inherited code nightmare.

Answer (score 11):

When you view it in Chrome's Developer tools, the result is after modified by javascript.
*(It means you could see contents added by javascript dynamically)*

When you view it as view source, it is the original html source.

Comment: None of the existing javascript files nor the page itself have changed in a few weeks, and this issue started appearing yesterday though. I definitely agree that it HAS to be a script injecting it, but I certainly can't find any code that might possibly be doing it. That being said, this is some really smelly coding here and I'm sure it is buried somewhere in that heaping pile of code :)